# How to reapply IntelliJ IDEA keyboard scheme?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.1

A couple of days ago I resetted Visual Studio settings. All keyboard shortcuts were assigned to their default values. I applied IntelliJ IDEA scheme back but it seems like some Visual Studio shortcuts are not removed and some ReSharper shortcuts are not added.

I had to remove a bunch of Visual Studio shortcuts starting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to make the ReSharper <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> shortcut work(same issues with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcuts and more). How can I make sure those unwanted shortcuts are removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting keyboard settings from my computer at home. It seems like ReSharper can't apply its scheme back.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in succession:

1. Go to *Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard*, and click *Reset*
   for the default scheme.
2. Go to *ReSharper > Options > Environment > Visual Studio
   Integration*, choose *ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA* and click
   *Apply Scheme*.